# Cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Description
I am experiencing a local error, the development cannot read property of 'childImageSharp' of undefined.

Steps to reproduce
https://github.com/aaronearl/thurz-party

run: `gatsby develop`

Expected result
The expected result is to display the image 'LATHURZ' below the event section. however, this is not happening. I am getting the above-mentioned error "cannot read property 'childImageSharp' of undefined.

Actual result
The actual result is childImageSharp of undefined

What happened. I have examined my query:

```
query Images {
image: file(relativePath: { eq: "lathurz.jpg" }) {
childImageSharp {
fixed(width: 400) {
...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
}
fluid {
...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
}
}
}
}
```

I believe it's correct it performs in the playground correctly.

Environment
System:

```
OS: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2677M CPU @ 1.80GHz
Shell: 5.0.8 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 11.4.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.12.3 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.8.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Languages:
Python: 2.7.15 - /usr/local/bin/python
Browsers:
Chrome: 77.0.3865.120
Safari: 9.1.2
npmPackages:
gatsby: ^2.0.64 => 2.15.36
gatsby-image: ^2.0.15 => 2.2.27
gatsby-plugin-manifest: ^2.0.5 => 2.2.21
gatsby-plugin-netlify: ^2.0.6 => 2.1.19
gatsby-plugin-offline: ^2.0.11 => 2.2.10
gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: ^3.0.0 => 3.1.11
gatsby-plugin-sharp: ^2.0.7 => 2.2.29
gatsby-plugin-styled-components: ^3.0.4 => 3.1.9
gatsby-source-filesystem: ^2.0.11 => 2.1.31
gatsby-transformer-json: ^2.1.6 => 2.2.13
gatsby-transformer-sharp: ^2.1.4 => 2.2.21
npmGlobalPackages:
gatsby-cli: 2.7.28
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, I believe the problem is that "pageQuery" is actually two separate queries.
Instead of:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query indexQuery {
    [...]
  }
  query Images {
    image: file(relativePath: { eq: "lathurz.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fixed(width: 400) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
        }
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

try:

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query{
    [...]
    image: file(relativePath: { eq: "lathurz.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fixed(width: 400) {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
        }
        fluid {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```